Inserting large JSON file into SQL Server table
I have a 3 GB json file and I am trying to insert it into a SQL Server table's column, using this code:
SELECT BulkColumn
INTO Temp
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '##path_to_json_file##', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

I am getting an error

Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes

I looked, searched, read documentation... but I could not find answer of HOW to load large file into database.
So, it is NOT possible? (And yes, I want to insert it all into one single column)

The limit for tables is 2GB - 1, so you can't. You could perhaps use COMPRESS function, but not sure it will work, since i don't have a 3gb json file at hand. You might be able to put the file into a variable and shred it to smaller pieces though.

@siggemannen Hi, thanks for recommending COMPRESS function, it worked, now I am trying to find out how to query it :D

You can do something like: SELECT * FROM YourTable CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CAST(DECOMPRESS(jsonCol) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) x etc. But still not sure it will work

Thanks for helping, but after ~20s of execution I got JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '≻' is found at position 0.

Oh, maybe it should be CAST(... AS VARCHAR(MAX)) since you used CLOB and not NCLOB, sorry :)

It does beg the question, why store such a large file in your database? It's not best practice.

@DaleK School :)

It's not possible. The maximum size for a single column entry is < 2 GB (2^31-1 B) . See Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server.
